# How to remove h3 tag from the reply-title

Tags: comments, html, comments-template

I would like to remove the h3 tag on "reply-title"[image: see screen shot]

I tried the following code :

```
    ob_start();
}
add_action( 'comment_form_before', 'my_comment_form_before' );

function my_comment_form_after() {
    $html = ob_get_clean();
    $html = preg_replace(
        '/<h3 id="reply-title"(.*)>(.*)<\/h3>/',
        '<p id="reply-title"\1>\2</p>',
        $html
    );
    echo $html;
}
add_action( 'comment_form_after', 'my_comment_form_after' );
```

It did work as it removed the h3 tag. But it also changed how the "Leave a comment" mention looks like. [image]

Is it possible just to remove the h3 tag without changing anything else ?